# How to convert column rows into a string variable using Spark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

**I need to convert single-column rows into a string variable for use in a where condition while loading from a DB table, instead of loading the entire data from the table.**

*Sample dataframe like below.*

| depName | emp_name |
| --- | --- |
| develop | Astrid |
| develop | Freja |
| develop | Wilma |
| sales | Maja |
| sales | Alice |
| personnel | John |
| personnel | Marsh |

*Expecting output like below, pls help me.*

*val data='develop','develop','develop','sales','sales','sales','personnel','personnel'*

*I tried the below logic but COLLECT method taking more time*

*val result = df.select("depName").collect().map(_.getString(0)).mkString(",")*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `select` the column, `collect` it. It'll return an array of Row.
We'll map over the rows and use `getString` to convert each value to a string.
Finally, `mkString` would make an overall string of them with a "," as a delimiter.

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
          val df = List(
            ("develop", "astrid"),
            ("develop", "Freja"),
            ("develop", "Wilma"),
            ("sales", "Maja"),
            ("sales", "Alice"),
            ("personnel", "John"),
            ("personnel", "Marsh")
          ).toDF("depName", "emp_name")
    
          val result = df.select("depName").collect().map(_.getString(0)).mkString(",")
```

Comment: Hi @ shalnarkftw, thank you for your answer. Is there an alternative to using COLLECT? COLLECT slows down the streaming application.

Comment: You can deal with your DF, filter, map or whatever you need with it, and then write it to a file. That's the best way to avoid loading large data into memory.